# D'avance, par avance, à l'avance et la perception de l''emploi pléonastique avec certains verbes etc. ?

Tags: régionalismes, lexique, locutions

On a les locutions adverbiales concurrentes *d'avance*, *par avance* et *à l'avance*, « par anticipation » ou  « avant le temps fixé ou prévu » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avance)) qu'on reconnaît égales depuis 1986 (Le bon usage, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>,  §966 a) alors que [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/avance) avait jugé la dernière « non conforme au bon usage » malgré ses [propres](https://www.littre.org/definition/revolver) [exemples](https://www.littre.org/definition/confection) (LBU14) ; la première est la plus fréquente (LBU14). On a des sensibilités différentes aux pléonasmes, surtout formels et étymologiques, avec des verbes préfixés en [pré-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9-) qui les accompagneraient (LBU14 §173 7 b), vu leur idée d'antériorité plus claire etc. On donne aussi [1748](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1061517/f428.image) C.C. (vs. [nouveau](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=5ED2AA4022E6D6931F72E724FAB74335.tplgfr26s_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006443034&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721&dateTexte=20181128)) comme autre exemple d'emploi de la locution *à l'avance* :

> L'acquéreur qui veut user de la faculté réservée par le bail
>   d'expulser le locataire en cas de vente est, en outre, tenu de
>   l'avertir au temps **d'avance** usité dans le lieu pour les congés.
>
> Il doit aussi avertir le fermier des biens ruraux, au moins un an **à
>   l'avance**.
>
> [ [*Code civil*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1061517/f428.image) (ancien) (France), art. 1748 ]

- Comment analyse-t-on la locution adverbiale dans *avertir au temps d'avance usité* ; indépendamment du texte de l'article, perçoit-on l'emploi de ces locutions avec des verbes comme *annoncer*, *commander* (ou *avertir*...) moins/autant/davantage pléonastique qu'avec *prévenir* ou *préparer*, par exemple ?
- Y a-t-il des régions où généralement *par avance* ou *à l'avance* sont plus fréquents que *d'avance* dans des tours comme *merci d'avance/par avance/à l'avance* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] au temps d’avance usité dans le lieu [...]

Si l’on désire mentionner qu’en un certain moment, antérieur à un autre, un avertissement doit être donné, et que la période séparant l’avertissement pourrait varier de lieu en lieu, comment s’y prend-on linguistiquement pour exprimer le tout sans tomber dans l’amphigouri ? La tournure utilisée ici me semble particulièrement claire, bien tournée, concise et appropriée.

Mes quelques essais pour trouver d’autres méthodes d’expression aboutirent rapidement à l’impasse :

- [...] est tenu de l’avertir tant de temps d’avance, correspondant à la période habituelle dans le lieu [...]
  → **NON !** Trop long, trop embirlificoté, en plus de la présence d’homonymes côte-à-côte (mais c’est de moindre importance).
- [...] est tenu de l’avertir, de lui laisser le temps de délai habituel dans le lieu avant de [...]
  → NON. Que veut donc dire de toute manière *laisser le temps*, quant on parle d’un locataire évincé ? Trop sujet à interprétation.

---

Comment analyser la tournure utilisée, alors ?

Réfléchissons tout d’abord au temps que l’on indique. Il s’agit d’un moment *(**au temps**, c’est-à-dire « en ce temps-là qui sera défini par la suite »)* dans l’écoulement général du Temps (avec un grand T), que l’on définit comme *en précédant un autre* *(**d’avance**)*, d’une période telle qu’habituelle ou ***usitée*** en un lieu indiqué *(**dans le lieu**)*. C’est donc un moment que l’on définit relativement à un autre, selon une échelle qui varie selon le lieu, mais qui est définie néanmoins pour chaque lieu.

---

#### Pléonasme ?

Il va de soi que l’avertissement précède habituellement l’effet. À ce titre, on peut en effet se demander si ***d’avance*** était parfaitement nécessaire.

Et il semble bien qu’il est nécessaire, car il sert à positionner le point zéro, l’éviction, à partir duquel on se doit de positionner l’avertissement. Sans cette précision, on pourrait chipoter et dire que le temps usité pour l’avertissement est un point absolu dans le temps, par exemple que c’est samedi matin ou le 4 du mois à midi, point à la ligne, l’éviction fut-elle due pour l’après-midi même. En version modifiée pour illustration :

> <sub>L’acquéreur qui veut user de la faculté réservée par le bail d’expulser le locataire en cas de vente est, en outre, tenu de **l’avertir au temps usité** dans le lieu pour les congés.</sub>

Grâce à ce petit *d’avance*, on force une mesure de temps relative, et une période, un délai fixe, et non pas un temps fixe avec une période ou un délai fonction de la position temporelle de l’éviction par rapport à ce temps fixe.

**Pas un pléonasme, donc**, mais une précision nécessaire...

...du moins avec *« avertir »*. Qu’en serait-il si un autre terme était utilisé, un terme que l’on retrouve plus souvent dans la liste des suspects de la section *Pléonasmes vicieux (à éviter votre vie dut-elle en dépendre)* des manuels de grammaire habituels ? Un terme, par exemple, commençant par PRÉ-, marqué d’antécédence dans la fabrique étymologique même de son être ? Un terme comme ***prévenir*** ? Ou comme ***préparer***, si le contexte était légèrement différent ?

Voyons voir ce que deviendrait le code ainsi modifié :

> <sub>L’acquéreur qui veut user de la faculté réservée par le bail d’expulser le locataire en cas de vente est, en outre, tenu de **le prévenir au temps d’avance usité** dans le lieu pour les congés.</sub>
>
> OU
>
> <sub>L’acquéreur qui veut user de la faculté réservée par le bail d’expulser le locataire en cas de vente est, en outre, tenu de **le prévenir au temps usité** dans le lieu pour les congés.</sub>

Pour les mêmes raisons de mauvaise foi précédemment invoquées, la seconde version prête à interprétation *(un cas extrême : un kiosque est ouvert de minuit à une heure du matin, le lendemain de Noël, pour distribuer les avis d’éviction, à charge pour les occupants de voir si un avis les concerne)*.

De nouveau, *d’avance* concerne *le temps*, et non le verbe *(avertir, prévenir, etc.)*, et sert à marquer l’absolu de la période intermédiaire, entre l’avis d’éviction et l’éviction elle-même, plutôt que l’absolu du moment d’émission de l’avis.

Comment: Hahaha, je n'avais pas vu _à l'avance_ dans la partie ancienne visant le fermier qui n'existe plus dans la version actuelle. Je suis dans les patates ! Ça fait donc du sens que le LBU parlait de l'ancienne version. Le LBU ne donnait pas textuellement l'exemple, uniquement la référence... Merci !

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Il me resterait à étudier les usages locaux, mais je ne suis pas très calé en la chose, aussitôt que ledit local de l’usage sort du français d’Amérique... Sauf coup de chance, je laisserai la chose à d’autres. Merci.

Comment: J'ai ajouté un dernier détail, concernant l’usage avec **prévenir** ou autres termes en PRÉ-. Bien désolé que tout ceci ne vous aura pas été très utile au final, mais ce fut pour moi, en dépit du maigre résultat, un beau parcours dans les méandres tortueux du pléonasme, que je n'aurais probablement pas accompli sans cette double erreur d'inattention que nous fîmes.

Comment: C'est bien vrai pour la réponse sur le tutoiement, j'avais oublié ça... peut-être qu'inconsciemment j'ai un intérêt plus grand que ce que je pensais ! Aussi, je voulais dire sur ce site-ci, je m'intéresse parfois à des trucs plus théoriques ailleurs. Je veux certainement pas décourager l'intérêt pour ce sujet-là, surtout dans le monde d'aujourd'hui ! Merci !